# Binding ProgressBar to MediaElement Value Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, .net-4.5, mediaelement

I am creating a WPF application which has a `MediaElement` that plays video. I didn't like the way the `Slider` control looked. I therefore I attempted, mostly successfully to use a `ProgressBar` in its place.

I have implemented functionality for clicking the `ProgressBar` to set the value of both itself and that of the position of the `MediaElement`. However when I also implemented a `DispatcherTimer` to increment the value of the `ProgressBar` alongside this functionality I am getting an oddity that I cannot work out where it is coming from.

Basically when I click on the `ProgressBar`, the fill correctly updates to where the cursor is (I am setting it directly in `setProgressBarPosition`), but then moves back a bit (I am guessing, when the `_Tick` method call is made of the `DispatcherTimer`, which is setting the `ProgressBar.Value` based on the position of `meVideo`).

The MSPaint arrow shows where I clicked, the red fill shows where it updated to, the gap between the cursor click and the position of the fill gets larger the later in the timeline I click which makes me think I have made a mistake in a calculation somewhere:

[image: Screenshot]

I am thinking I have probably done something wrong in the setting of `meVideo.Position` in `pgbVideo_MouseUp` but I can't see it. Here is my code:

```
private void videoTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isDragging)
    { 
        pgbVideo.Value = meVideo.Position.TotalSeconds;
    }
}

/*
* Handles the clicking of the video timeline.
*/
private void pgbVideo_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double mousePosition = e.GetPosition(pgbVideo).X;
    setProgressBarPosition(mousePosition);

    isDragging = true;
}

/*
* Handles the dragging of the mouse over the video timeline.
*/
private void pgbVideo_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        double mousePosition = e.GetPosition(pgbVideo).X;
        setProgressBarPosition(mousePosition);
    }
}

/*
* Sets the position of the video timeline progressbar.
*/
private void setProgressBarPosition(double mousePosition)
{
    if (meVideo.Source != null)
    {
        double progressBarPosition = mousePosition / pgbVideo.ActualWidth * pgbVideo.Maximum;

        pgbVideo.Value = progressBarPosition;
    }
}

/*
* Sets the position of the media element.
*/
private void pgbVideo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (meVideo.Source != null)
    {
        double videoPositon = meVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks * (pgbVideo.Value / pgbTime.Maximum);

        meVideo.Position = new TimeSpan((int)videoPositon);
    }

    isDragging = false;
}
```

Thanks for reading, any help appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my `_MediaOpened` method where I set the maximum value of the `ProgressBar`:

```
private void meVideo_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbVideo.Maximum = meVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;

    videoTimer.Start();

    isPlaying = true;
}
```

Comment: *I didn't like the way the Slider control looked* you can retemplate the control to what you like, that's why WPF's so amazing.

Comment: what your Max value of the prograss bar ?

Comment: @KingKing tough you are correct , for someone who isn't a strong XAML programmer a Slider is difficult control to re template.

Comment: @eranotzap is right... did you set the `Slider.Maximum` value to the correct value when you loaded the video?

Comment: @eranotzap - I have edited the original post with where I set the Maximum.

Comment: It seems fine actually , i can't see it just by looking at it . 
I want to know 3 things : 
1) The value of Maximum 
2) Click at the beginning tell me what X is .
3) Click at the End and tell me what X is .
4) and you know what just to be sure , your not setting Minimum somewhere right ..?

Comment: I can recreate the symptom, but only if replacing `pgbVideo.ActualWidth` with `this.ActualWidth` (the window's ActualWidth)- ;)

Comment: Can you have a look at my full code to see if you can see where it differs from what you have? .cs - http://pastebin.com/3cjbf320 .xaml - http://pastebin.com/3sWEBzby

Comment: @eranotzap - 1) 92.0 (although depends on the video I select). 2) 0. 3) 774. 4) Minimum is set to 0 in designer properties, not set in code.

Comment: @blawford what's pgbVideo ActualWidth ?

Comment: It still seams fine :| , i can't find any fualts .. 
The only thing i can think about is maybe when changing videos you don't reset you Maximum value maybe it's the Maximum of the previous video or something like that , your code seems fine .. debug it

Comment: Only used one video with this program, so it won't be that. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: And I've just spotted the mistake! `double videoPositon = meVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks * (pgbVideo.Value / pgbTime.Maximum);` in `pgbVideo_MouseUp`. I am mistakenly dividing the value of `pgbVideo` against `pgbTime`, which is the `ProgressBar` below the one I am concerned with (to the left of '35' in the screenshot), which has it's Maximum set to 100. Annoying that the video I was using was 92 seconds otherwise the problem may have been more immediately obvious!

Thanks to everyone that tried to help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly it was a simple mistake made by me being too quick on the IntelliSense! In `pgbVideo_MouseUp` the line:

```
double videoPositon = meVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks * (pgbVideo.Value / pgbTime.Maximum);
```

Should be:

```
double videoPositon = meVideo.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks * (pgbVideo.Value / pgbVideo.Maximum);
```

`pgbTime` refers to another, unrelated `ProgressBar` which has the `Maximum` of 100. With the `TotalSeconds` of the loaded video being used to set the `Maximum` of `pgbVideo` and the video length being 92 seconds, the problem presented as an issue with accuracy (to me at least!), whereas if the video was 10 minutes the behaviour would have been way off and maybe led me to looking for a more obvious mistake!

Thanks to everyone that tried to help.

Comment: Ha, actually I noticed that, but I thought that was just a typo so I correct it;